# How do I see inside of a SQL Server database file

Tags: sql-server

I'm curious what inside of a SQL Server database (a `.mdf` file) since it has been 4 gb and how do I open it to find something interesting in it?

Comment: Use the related sql viewing software to look into it? MS SQL has sql server management studio

Comment: Thanks for the answer. any suggestion what trusted software should i use?

Comment: Essentially MDF is a binary file so you can’t use a text editor to look at the file and get anything of Value. @Agus has a good answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracted from [data-recovery-solutions](https://www.data-recovery-solutions.com/blog/view-open-mdf-file-without-sql-server/):

> MDF files are the primary database files of SQL database server and
>   they are saved as .MDF extension. Being the primary database, MDF
>   files store all the user database and other database objects like
>   tables, keys, indices, views, functions, columns, triggers etc. Also,
>   these files include all the startup info of the SQL Server database.
>   In an MS SQL Server, each database contains one primary MDF file.
>
> It is a binary kind of file which can’t be opened normally. It is the
>   main database file that can be attached to a running SQL Server to
>   access the database using SQL transaction Statements. But, these MDF
>   files are prone to corruption. Even a smaller corruption in MDF files
>   makes your entire database contents inaccessible.

[See here for a MDF viewer](https://www.data-recovery-solutions.com/sql-viewer.php)

Comment: This is the reason why i'm afraid to open it. to avoid a corruption since its a online database which cant be turn off. thanks anyway